# How to use Swift flags to detect a TestFlight build

Tags: swift, xcode, testflight

I'm trying to branch my code depending on whether the app build is a debug, release, TestFlight, or App Store one. There are 4 different options for specifying Swift compiler flags:

- `Appstore Release`
- `Debug`
- `Enterprise Release`
- `Release`.

Which of these four options corresponds to TestFlight builds?

[image: Other Swift Flags]

Comment: why dont you tell us, what you want to achieve? detecting a test run during a test to alter the execution path sounds purpose defeating.

Comment: I want to use a different service endpoint. TF and App Store builds should use prod, and ad-hoc builds should use a different one.